# Youtube API fails to load with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, youtube-api

I have a page written in HTML and PHP that attempts to load a youtube player with a custom id using the Youtube IFrame API. In my code, the div with the id `player` should hold the youtube player. my HTML:

```
    <?php
    include("server/session.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MuSync - Player</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/getvideo.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='player.css'></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1> head </h1>
            <div id='block'></div>
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var ytp;
            var owned = <?php echo $_SESSION['owned']; ?>;
            if(owned==<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>){
                owned = true;
            }
            ytp = document.getElementById('player');
            ytp.seekTo(10, true);
        </script>
    <!--    <input type="hidden" value="" id="videoId"/> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The other part of my code resides in `getvideo.js`, and it is as follows:

```
var vidId;
var time;
var video;

$(function(){

    var id = getUrlParameter('id');
    var jqxhr = $.ajax("server/getvideo.php?id=" + id)
        .done(function(response){
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            vidId = json['url'];
            time = json['time'];
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert("Action Failed...");
        });
});

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    video = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: vidId,
        playerVars: {'autoplay': 1, 'start': time}
    });
}
```

When trying to use the `seekTo` function in my main HTML page, the youtube player simply won't load any video and show me an error message. My final goal is to get every once in a while the current time that the video is playing in, but I can't seem to get the API running... Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What error does it display?

Comment: @JBaczuk Nothing special, just an empty player that says "an error occured". I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I might be accessing the player before it is loaded? I'm not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: do you get any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @JBAczuk Nothing, it is empty.

Comment: So a few questions.  Why aren't you using an iFrame with the iframe API? - Nevermind it looks like it replaces the div with an iframe.  And why don't you have the event triggers when you create the player?  I'm looking here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player